# DataTables render function with variable amount of table headers

Tags: javascript, datatables

I know, that the amount of table header columns and table data columns need to be the same when using DataTables.
My problem is that I'm now facing the problem that the amount of my `<th>` tags is conditionally +/- 2 and I'm using the render function to display the corresponding `<td>` cols.
It's not really surprising that DataTables throws an error on that (`Cannot read property 'style' of undefined`).
Anyway I neither see a chance to get rid of the render functions nor to statically render the table headers.
Is there a way to statisfy DataTables, when there is no table header for the particular column?

```
columns: [
   {
   data: "some_id",
   render: function (data, type, row) {
      return "some content";
   },
   {
    data: "some_id", 
    render: function (data, type, row) {
       return "some content";
   }
]
```

Here is the part which is causing the trouble.

Comment: I am not sure if there is a better way, but I have always just stuck empty <th></th> in the header to satisfy the column count

Comment: @PaulZepernick You could post this as an answer, because I think it's a sufficient workaround! So easy, I couldn't think of it. :D

Comment: Glad to help, I posted an answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataTables requires the amount of columns in the `<thead>` to match the column count in the `<tbody>`.  Adding columns in the column:[] array that don't have a associated column in the `<thead>` will produce a internal DataTable JS error.  This can be worked around by adding an empty `<th></th>` in the header for columns that are using the render.

```
<table>
     <thead>
          <th>Column 1</th>
          <th>Column 2</th>
          <th></th>
     </thead>
</table>
```

DataTable columns property

```
columns: [
   {data: "column1"},
   {data: "column2"},
   {
         data: "some_id", 
         render: function (data, type, row) {
            return "some content";
         },
         sortable: false, // optional
         searchable: false // optional
   }
]
```

As an additional tip, it may be beneficial to add sortable, searchable false along with the render when adding items in, such as, a button through the render.  This will avoid problems with the user potentially trying to sort or search on a column that is display only or has an actionable item that is not available for search and sort.